# Can't use double middleware route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-9, laravel-middleware

i have route api code like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api','web'], function(){
    Route::get('user', 'Api\AuthController@user');
    Route::get('kurir', 'Api\AuthController@kurir');
    Route::get('droppoint', 'Api\DroppointController@index');
    Route::get('droppoint/{id}', 'Api\DroppointController@show');
    Route::post('droppoint', 'Api\DroppointController@store');
    Route::put('droppoint/{id}', 'Api\DroppointController@update');
    Route::delete('droppoint/{id}', 'Api\DroppointController@destroy');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:kurirs-api','web'], function(){
    Route::get('user', 'Api\AuthController@user');
    Route::get('kurir', 'Api\AuthController@kurir');
    Route::get('droppoint', 'Api\DroppointController@index');
    Route::get('droppoint/{id}', 'Api\DroppointController@show');
    Route::post('droppoint', 'Api\DroppointController@store');
    Route::put('droppoint/{id}', 'Api\DroppointController@update');
    Route::delete('droppoint/{id}', 'Api\DroppointController@destroy');
});
```

I want to make login program with two role "user" and "kurir".

My question is why its just authorized the last one "kurirs-api", and if i access the first one its show unauthenticated? and if i change the position, it's only authorized "auth:api". What to do to make the code can authorize "api" and "kurirs-api"?

I have searching in the internet but the problem still doesnt solve

Comment: `auth:api,kurirs-api` .......

Answer (score 3):

if you want to have multiple middlewares, you have to make it an array:

```php
// like this
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:kurirs-api','web']], function() {
    //
});
```

Comment: still unauthenticated if i login using "auth:api"

Comment: it should pass both middlewares, are you sure it passes?

Comment: yes, i also have try to change it to "Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','web']], function()" and it only authorized if i login using auth:api token

Comment: it doesn't make sense to use both `api` & `web`, it should be either `api` or `web`, as each one do different work, web is for browser `stuff`

Comment: so what i gonna do if i want authorized using both api (auth:api & auth:kurirs-api)?

Comment: use `auth:api` & `auth:kurirs-api`, not `web`

Comment: thank you sir, it's work when i change it to `auth:api,kurirs-api`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to have multiple middlewares you need to use array

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function() {
  //your route here 
});
```

Comment: This is the same answer that has already been posted.